# Batch file creation for restarting services remotely

Tags: batch-file

Need to create a batch file for restarting some services remotely and restarting iis remotely in Admin mode.

Help would be appreciated

Thanks
krish

Comment: Can you give more info - Like which service you want to start?  How important is error checking?

Answer (score 1):

SC and net start net stop are the way to go.

[MS KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/166819) link for SC.

[Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736564%28WS.10%29.aspx) on net commands.

there's also [iisrest](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/003ed2fe-6339-4919-b577-6aa965994a9b.mspx?mfr=true) which is a command line utility specifically for IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use SC?
http://ss64.com/nt/sc.html

Comment: I want batch file commands so that i can execute the batch file.

Comment: So... put it in a batch file.

A batch file is merely a series of otherwise single command lines.

If you read the link I posted, you'd find examples.
Examples like:
sc \\server1 start schedule
sc \\server4 start messenger
sc \\server1 stop schedule
sc \\server4 stop messenger
sc \\webserver stop w3svc
sc \\webserver start w3svc

Answer (score 0):

+1 for SC

To elevate past UAC (if that is what you mean by run with admin privileges) you can use elevate.cmd - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.06.utilityspotlight.aspx?pr=blog